# Conditionally populate new columns using split on another column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, split

I have a dataframe

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({'col1': [1,2,1,2], 'col2': ['aa bb cc', 'ee-ff-gg', 'hh ii kk', 'll-mm-nn']})
```

I want to:

- Split col2 on the ' ' where col1==1
- Split on the '-' where col1==2
- Append this data to 3 new columns: (col20, col21, col22)

Ideally the code would look like this:

```py
subdf=df.loc[df['col1']==1]
#list of columns to use
col_list=['col20', 'col21', 'col22']
#append to dataframe new columns from split function
subdf[col_list]=(subdf.col2.str.split(' ', 2, expand=True)
```

however this hasn't worked.

I have tried using **merge** and **join**, however:

- join doesn't work if the columns are already populated
- merge doesn't work if they aren't.

I have also tried:

```py
#subset dataframes
subdf=df.loc[df['col1']==1]
subdf2=df.loc[df['col1']==2]

#trying the join method, only works if columns aren't already present
subdf.join(subdf.col2.str.split(' ', 2, expand=True).rename(columns={0:'col20', 1:'col21', 2: 'col22'}))
#merge doesn't work if columns aren't present
subdf2=subdf2.merge(subdf2.col2.str.split('-', 2, expand=True).rename(columns={0:'col20', 1:'col21', 2: 'col22'}))
subdf2
```

the error messages when I run it:

```py
subdf2=subdf2.merge(subdf2.col2.str.split('-', 2, expand=True).rename(columns={0:'col20', 1:'col21', 2: 'col22'})

MergeError: No common columns to perform merge on. Merge options: left_on=None, right_on=None, left_index=False, right_index=False
```

### EDIT givin information after mark's comment on regex

My original col1 was actually the regex combination I had used to extract col2 from some strings.

```py
#the combination I used to extract the col2
combinations= ['(\d+)[-](\d+)[-](\d+)[-](\d+)', '(\d+)[-](\d+)[-](\d+)'... ]
```

here is the original dataframe

```py
col1                          col2 
(\d+)[-](\d+)[-](\d+)[-](\d+) 350-300-50-10 
(\d+)[-](\d+)[-](\w+)(\d+)    150-180-G31
```

I then created a dictionary that connected every combination to what the split values of col2 represented:

```py
filtermap={'(\d+)[-](\d+)[-](\w+)(\d+)': 'thickness temperature sample', '(\d+)[-](\d+)[-](\d+)[-](\d+)': 'thickness temperature width height' }
```

with this filter I wanted to:

- Subset the dattaframe based on regex combinations
- use split on col2 to find the values corresponding to the combination using the filtermap (thickness temperature..)
- add these values to the new columns on the dataframe

```py
col1                          col2           thickness temperature width length sample
(\d+)[-](\d+)[-](\d+)[-](\d+) 350-300-50-10  350       300         50    10
(\d+)[-](\d+)[-](\w+)(\d+)    150-180-G31    150       180                        G31
```

since you mentioned regex maybe you know of a way to do this directly ?

### EDIT 2; input-output

in the input there are strings like so:

```py
'this is the first example string 350-300-50-10 ', 
'this is the second example string 150-180-G31'
```

formats that are:

- number-number-number-number(350-300-50-10 ) have this orded information in them: thickness(350)-temperature(300)-width(50)-length(10)
- number-number-letternumber (150-180-G31 ) have this ordered information in them: thickness-temperature-sample

desired output:

```py
col2,          thickness, temperature, width, length, sample 

350-300-50-10  350        300          50     10       None
150-180-G31    150        180          None   None     G31
```

I used eg:

```py
re.search('(\d+)[-](\d+)[-](\d+)[-](\d+)'))
```

to find the col2 in the strings

Comment: `rsplit` might work. https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.rsplit.html

Comment: the split works, but I am not able to create 3 new columns populated with the results of the split. The subsetting is giving me the main issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `np.where` to simplify this problem.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame({'col1': [1,2,1,2],
                   'col2': ['aa bb cc', 'ee-ff-gg', 'hh ii kk', 'll-mm-nn']
                   })


temp = np.where(df['col1'] == 1, #a boolean array/series indicating where the values are equal to 1.
                df['col2'].str.split(' '), #Use the output of this if True
                df['col2'].str.split('-') #Else use this.
                )

temp_df = pd.DataFrame(temp.tolist()) #create a new dataframe with the columns we need
#Output:
    0   1   2
0  aa  bb  cc
1  ee  ff  gg
2  hh  ii  kk
3  ll  mm  nn
```

Now just assign the result back to the original df. You can use a concat or join, but a simple assignment suffices as well.

```
df[[f'col2_{i}' for i in temp_df.columns]] = temp_df

print(df)
   col1      col2 col2_0 col2_1 col2_2
0     1  aa bb cc     aa     bb     cc
1     2  ee-ff-gg     ee     ff     gg
2     1  hh ii kk     hh     ii     kk
3     2  ll-mm-nn     ll     mm     nn
```

---

EDIT: To address more than two conditional splits

If you need more than two conditions, `np.where` was only designed to work for a binary selection. You can Opt for a "custom" approach that works with as many splits as you like here.

```
splits = [ ' ', '-', '---']
all_splits = pd.DataFrame({s:df['col2'].str.split(s).values for s in splits})
#Output:
                            -         ---
0  [aa, bb, cc]    [aa bb cc]  [aa bb cc]
1    [ee-ff-gg]  [ee, ff, gg]  [ee-ff-gg]
2  [hh, ii, kk]    [hh ii kk]  [hh ii kk]
3    [ll-mm-nn]  [ll, mm, nn]  [ll-mm-nn]
```

First we split `df['col2']` on all splits, without expanding. Now, it's just a question of selecting the correct `list` based on the value of `df['col1']`

We can use numpy's advanced indexing for this.

```
temp = all_splits.values[np.arange(len(df)), df['col1']-1]
```

After this point, the steps should be same as above, starting with creating `temp_df`

Comment: this looks good, for the colnames, can I pass a list of column names instead of using the f'col2_{I}' ?

Comment: Yep, you can pass your own list of columns or change the logic around as needed. `[f'col2_{i}' for i in temp_df.columns]` Would need to change if you wish to make a list with your own column names.

Comment: ok, and can I use the np.where if I have more than 2 conditions? like ' ', '-' ,'---'? or would I have to use 2 where statements?

Comment: np.where expects only two outputs (one for True, one for False), so you'd either have to chain the np.where statements or try a different approach.

Comment: In case of multiple conditions, try `np.select`

Comment: @David8 You might want to try regex to solve your split issue without invoking `where`, `df['col2'].str.split(' |-|---',expand=True)`

Comment: regex is a good approach if your characters for splitting will not occur in conflict with each other.

Comment: @ParitoshSingh took me a  while to figure out how your solution worked, but it does!! thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You are pretty close. To generate a column based on some condition, `where` is often handy, see code below,

```
col2_exp1 = df.col2.str.split(' ',expand=True)
col2_exp2 = df.col2.str.split('-',expand=True)

col2_combine = (col2_exp1.where(df.col1.eq(1),col2_exp2)
                         .rename(columns=lambda x:f'col2{x}'))
```

Finally,

```
df.join(col2_combine)
```

Comment: since you mentioned regex and I had it in my original code I added an edit showing how I had used it, maybe you know of a way to get what I want directly from the regex ?

Comment: I thought I had provided the solution, no?  The new edit confuses me a bit.. an input and expected output sample will be helpful.

Comment: new at python so could have definitely written the question better. 
But in my actual data I have more than 2 values for col1, so I cant use where as I have more than 2 subsets. In my actual data, col1 values are the actual regex I used to originally extract the col2 values from a string eg. from 'an example string 350-300-50-10' I used (\d+)[-](\d+)[-](\d+)[-](\d+) to get '350-300-50-10' and put col1: (\d+)[-](\d+)[-](\d+)[-](\d+), col2:  '350-300-50-10'.I also know that when the data is in the format: (\d+)[-](\d+)[-](\d+)[-](\d+) the values correspond to: Thickness-Temperature-Length-Width

Comment: @David8, my apologies. I couldn't figure out what are you trying to achieve after reading the description several times, as a lot of terminologies you use are not exactly consistent with my understanding. The easiest way is probably just to show what is the input and what does the expected output look like.

Comment: my fault for not being clear, I've added a second edit with an input output example, in reality I have more than  2 different combinations